# SQL query for book users, reviews and given ratings

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need a query which will display top 7 users by the total indicator of reviews written and ratings given, indicating the total number of pages in the books to which they reviewed

Structure of 3 tables given:

- `Books`: book_id, author_id, title, num_pages, publication_date, publisher_id
- `Ratings`: rating_id, book_id, username, rating
- `Reviews`: review_id, book_id, username, text

Queries I tried this far

```
SELECT
    username,
    SUM(reviews.reviews_id) AS total_reviews,
    SUM(ratings.rating) AS total_ratings,
    SUM(books.num_pages) AS total_pages
FROM 
    reviews
JOIN 
    ratings ON reviews.book_id = ratings.book_id
            AND reviews.username = ratings.username
JOIN 
    books ON books.book_id = reviews.book_id
GROUP BY 
    username
ORDER BY 
    total_reviews + total_ratings DESC
LIMIT 7;
```

Comment: So what's wrong with the query you've posted?

Comment: Column username ambiguous. needs to be qualified.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: Per jarlh's comment, you have `username` in your `select` and `group by` sections, but you've made clear that there are at least 2 username columns; one on `reviews`, one on `ratings`.  Though these have the same value, you have to tell your statement which to use, so replace `username` with `reviews.username` in the `select` and `group by` sections.

Answer (score 0):

try this query :

```
SELECT
    username,
    SUM(reviews_count) AS total_reviews,
    SUM(ratings_sum) AS total_ratings,
    SUM(total_pages) AS total_pages
FROM (
    SELECT
        r.username,
        COUNT(DISTINCT r.review_id) AS reviews_count,
        SUM(rt.rating) AS ratings_sum,
        SUM(b.num_pages) AS total_pages
    FROM reviews r
    JOIN ratings rt ON r.book_id = rt.book_id AND r.username = rt.username
    JOIN books b ON r.book_id = b.book_id
    GROUP BY r.username, r.book_id
) AS subquery
GROUP BY username
ORDER BY total_reviews + total_ratings DESC
LIMIT 7;
```

Comment: this also wrong query. Displays mistake on penultimate line: ORDER BY total_reviews + total_ratings DESC

Answer (score 0):

`total_ratings` and `total_reviews` are not recognized ! Use your query as a subquery then apply the order and limit on it :

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT
    re.username,
    SUM(re.reviews_id) AS total_reviews,
    SUM(ra.rating) AS total_ratings,
    SUM(b.num_pages) AS total_pages
  FROM reviews re
  JOIN ratings ra
    ON re.book_id = ra.book_id
    AND re.username = ra.username
  JOIN books b
    ON b.book_id = re.book_id
  GROUP BY re.username
) AS s
ORDER BY total_reviews + total_ratings DESC
LIMIT 7;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to `FULL [OUTER] JOIN` between reviews and ratings.

```sql
SELECT
    username,
    COUNT(*) AS total_books,
    COUNT(review_id) AS total_reviews,
    COUNT(rating_id) AS total_ratings,
    SUM(b.num_pages) AS total_pages,
    COUNT(review_id) + COUNT(rating_id) AS total_indicator
FROM reviews re
FULL JOIN ratings USING (book_id, username)
JOIN books b USING (book_id)
GROUP BY username
ORDER BY total_indicator DESC
LIMIT 7;
```

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ls-_SZxn)

Answer (score 0):

I tested this query on sample tables I created and it seems to be working.

```
SELECT u.username,
       COALESCE(SUM(r.rating), 0) AS total_ratings,
       COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT r.book_id), 0) AS rated_books,
       COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT rv.book_id), 0) AS reviewed_books,
       COALESCE(SUM(b.num_pages), 0) AS total_pages_reviewed
FROM (
    SELECT username FROM Ratings
    UNION
    SELECT username FROM Reviews
) AS u
LEFT JOIN Ratings r ON u.username = r.username
LEFT JOIN Reviews rv ON u.username = rv.username
LEFT JOIN Books b ON rv.book_id = b.book_id
GROUP BY u.username
ORDER BY (COALESCE(SUM(r.rating), 0) + COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT rv.book_id), 0)) DESC
LIMIT 7;
```